# Plotly Library do not showed anything

Tags: python, charts, google-colaboratory, plotly-python

I tried to plot a scatter plot using plotly libraries.

[image]

```
import chart_studio.plotly as py
import plotly.offline as pyoff
import plotly.graph_objs as go

#plot monthly sales
plot_data = [
    go.Scatter(
        x=df['date'],
        y=df['qty'],
    )
]

plot_layout = go.Layout(
        title='Montly Sold'
    )
fig = go.Figure(data=plot_data, layout=plot_layout)
pyoff.iplot(fig)
fig.show()
```

The output is just a blank
[image]

How to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have the `chart_studio` installed but it seems it wasn't used anyway in your code. So after commenting `chart_studio` import and adding some data to your `dataframe` I can successfully run your code in my IDE (Eclipse). However it was opening two windows with the same plot so I had to remove one of the two last lines so just one window opens.

Then I tried your code in local Jupyter Notebook and in hosted Google CoLab and it works fine with the following code:

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

rng = pd.date_range('2015-02-24', periods=5, freq='T')
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'date': rng, 'qty': np.random.randn(len(rng)) }) 

#plot monthly sales
plot_data = [
    go.Scatter(
        x=df['date'],
        y=df['qty'],
    )
]

plot_layout = go.Layout(
        title='Montly Sold'
    )
fig = go.Figure(data=plot_data, layout=plot_layout)
fig.show()
```

Or you could leave the `import plotly.offline as pyoff` and use `pyoff.iplot(fig)` instead of `fig.show()` which also works fine.

> **Note:** Running your code in Jupyter Notebook for the first time after (re-)starting you computer can take quite some time to generate and show a plot.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I am using google colab and wondering why this doesn't work for me. Anyway, thank you for your reply

Comment: Did you try to create a new Notebook and run the above code in it? Please note the "hourglass" icon in the browser tab after clicking the `Run` button, indicating that Jupyter is busy to generate a plot. Wait patiently without refreshing the page until the plot is being displayed